# What does the dot equals and dot colon syntax mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

What does the dot equals (`.=`) and dot colon (`.:`) syntax mean in this example taken from the Aeson JSON library?

```
instance ToJSON Coord where
  toJSON (Coord xV yV) = object [ "x" .= xV,
                              "y" .= yV ]

-- A FromJSON instance allows us to decode a value from JSON.  This
-- should match the format used by the ToJSON instance.

instance FromJSON Coord where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Coord <$>
                         v .: "x" <*>
                         v .: "y"
  parseJSON _          = empty
```

Full example on Github: https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/examples/Simplest.hs

Comment: They are functions from the `aeson` library. See this for more details: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.3/docs/Data-Aeson.html

Comment: Hoogle knows. [`(.:)`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=.%3A+%2Baeson) and [`(.=)`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=.%3D+%2Baeson)

Comment: In general, operators aren't really "syntax" in Haskell. With very few exceptions, they're just defined in libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comments are all correct.  You can Hoogle for these function and find the correct haddock documentation, which shows these operators are functions defined in a library and not some integral part of the Haskell language.  In general, a starting `.` is used by libraries to define infix functions because many other desirable symbols are either invalid for functions (ex `:.`) or the singular character is reserved syntax in Haskell (ex `=`, `:`).

`(.=)` is used to help create JSON objects while `.:` is for parsing JSON.  Normally with Aeson you have a one-to-one match between some data structure and some set of JSON messages, so for example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import Control.Monad (mzero)
data ServerMsg = ServerMsg.
                   { msgId :: Int
                   , msg   :: Text
                   } deriving (Show)
instance ToJSON ServerMsg where
    toJSON d = object [ "msgId" .= msgId d
                      , "msg"   .= msg d
                      ]
instance FromJSON ServerMsg where
    parseJSON (Object o) =
              ServerMsg <$> o .: "msgId" <*> o .: "msg"
    parseJSON _ = mzero    


testJSON :: Value
testJSON = toJSON (ServerMsg 398242 "Hello user3526171")

testParse :: Result ServerMsg
testParse = fromJSON testJSON
```

Now you can load this module in GHCi and play around easily:

```
*Main> testJSON
Object fromList [("msg",String "Hello user3526171"),("msgId",Number 398242.0)]
*Main> testParse 
Success (ServerMsg {msgId = 398242, msg = "Hello user3526171"})
```